# Most efficient way to use calculated value in multiple clauses without selecting it?

Tags: postgresql

What is the most efficient way to use a calculated value in multiple clauses without selecting it?

See (fictional) example below.

One approach is to calculate the value twice, but that feels unclean and inefficient:

```
SELECT
  price,
  sale_price
FROM products
WHERE (price - sale_price) > 10
ORDER BY (price - sale_price) DESC;
```

Another approach is to use a join, but that is quite slow:

```
SELECT
  price,
  sale_price,
FROM products
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT
    id,
    (price - sale_price) AS discount
  FROM products
) AS p ON products.id = p.id
WHERE p.discount > 10
ORDER BY p.discount DESC;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your last query is really not so bad :

```
SELECT price, sale_price, price - sale_price AS discount
FROM products
WHERE (price - sale_price) > 10
ORDER BY discount DESC
```

An alternative solution can be :

```
SELECT price, sale_price, discount
FROM products
CROSS JOIN LATERAL (price - sale_price) AS discount
WHERE discount > 10
ORDER BY discount DESC
```

but I don't really see the advantage. You can compare both solutions performances with `EXPLAIN ANALYSE` and share the results.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas. The actual calculated value is a lot more complex, I agree in this example that calculating the value twice isn't too bad.

Answer (score 2):

Use a derived table:

```
select *
from (
  SELECT price,
         sale_price,
         (price - sale_price) AS discount
  FROM products
) t
WHERE discount > 10
ORDER BY discount DESC;
```

Comment: Thanks, interesting idea. Sorry, I've had to modify the question to remove the alias from the WHERE clause.

Comment: You can still use a derived table: just don't select the `discount` column in the outer select.